# Is there a way to recover android photo?

Tags: android

How can I recover android photo because I deleted a important image long time ago and i changed custom ROM like 4 times after that.Is there a way to recover or not?Please help me.

I want back that image and I tried many recovery tool but I didn't get,may be because of changing ROM.

Comment: When you delete file you delete only one line from table of contents, you can find deleted things when they are not overridden. Use special software.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can get it back. Because all memory is rewritten